# how to drag a text string and its hyperlink from an HTML page to a TEdit

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I hope to to drag a text string and its hyperlink from an HTML page  to a TEdit.
For example

displays `aaa`

actual string is `<a href=somewhere.html>aaa</a>`

I try to use drag&drop vcl, but found that it only can catch `aaa` itself rather than the string and its hyperlink.

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go download Anders Melander's free [Drag and Drop Component Suite](http://melander.dk/delphi/dragdrop/). In it you'll find `TDropURLTarget` to put on your form. Set its `Target` property to refer to your `TEdit` control, and when a URL is dropped there, the component's `URL` and `Title` properties will be updated so you can inspect them during the `OnDrop` event handler. The suite comes with several examples; *TargetDemo* has the basics.

Comment: Thanks. I am using this vcl. I think it is only for grag&drop single hyperlink. I prefer to select a series of string , drag and drop to catch their hyperlinks one time.

Comment: But the browser doesn't send them one at a time, and you can't receive something that isn't sent. In your case, what's being dragged is a block of *text*, so it looks like you need to use a plain `TDropTarget` component and look for things that match either `THTMLClipboardFormat` or `TTextClipboardFormat`. Then parse the HTML in that text to find the hyperlinks. How to parse HTML may be covered in other questions here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Another good library is Raize DropMaster.

Anyway, I believe that it IS possible to do what you want, but maybe it'll turn out to be HTML or RTF drag/drop?  Hard to say.  I can, for example, drag/drop the list of hyperlinks on this page (over there to the right, under "RELATED") into Word, and they all show up, with hyperlinks on board. 
So it IS possible.  But I suspect that WinWord is dropping as HTML.

Anyway, Rob's suggestion of looking at examples is a good one - between that library and Raize, you should find something that you can use as a prototype.

Comment: Thanks. Raize Dropmaster also can do what I want.